# Characterization of the measurable sets in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical sets on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R}$ denote the collection of all functions $\tilde\omega : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all cylindrical subsets of $\tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R}$.  Similarly, let $\tilde\Omega_\mathbb{Z^+}$ denote the collection of all functions $\tilde\omega : \mathbb{Z^+} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Z^+}$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all cylindrical subsets of $\tilde\Omega_{\mathbb{Z^+}}$.

My question concerns the following characterization of the sets in $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$:

> $S \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ if and only if there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Z^+}}$ and an infinite sequence of real numbers $t_1, t_2, \dots$ such that 
>   $$
>  S = \left\{ \tilde\omega \in \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R} \, : \, \big( \tilde\omega(t_n) \big)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in B \right\}
> $$

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2178553/cylindrical-sets-and-minimal-sigma-algebras) that asks how to prove this characterization, and in the accepted answer an outline for the proof is provided.  The first step is to show that the collection of sets $\Sigma$ defined by
$$
 \Sigma := \Big\{ S \subseteq \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R} \, : \, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Z^+}, \, \{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } S = \left\{ \tilde\omega \in \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R} \, : \, \big( \tilde\omega(t_n) \big)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in B  \right\}  \Big\}
$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra.  **I am having difficulty in proving that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions.**

The following is my attempt.  I thought it would be helpful to think in terms of projections.  Specifically, for a sequence of real numbers $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, define $\pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}} : \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R} \to \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{Z^+}$ by $\pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}(\tilde\omega):=\big( \tilde\omega(t_n) \big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  Then  $S \in \Sigma$ iff there exists $B \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ and a projection $\pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}$ such that $S = \pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}^{-1}(B)$.  Moreover, $\Sigma$ is the family of all such pre-images where $B$ and the sequence of times range over all possibilities:
$$
\Sigma := \Big\{ S \subseteq \tilde\Omega_\mathbb{R} \, : \, \exists B \in \mathcal{B}_\mathbb{Z^+}, \, \{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ such that } S = \pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}^{-1}(B) \Big\} = \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Z}^+}} \bigcup_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}} \{\pi_{\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}^{-1}(B)\}
$$

Let $\{S_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \Sigma$, so there exists $\{t_{n,k}\}_{n,k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\{B_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{Z}^+}$ such that 
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \qquad S_n = \pi_{\{t_{n,k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}}^{-1}(B_n)
$$
We aim to show $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n \in \Sigma$.  I thought about trying to diagonalize the array of times to form a sequence $\{\tau_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$
$$
 \tau_1 := t_{1,1}, \, \tau_2 := t_{1,2}, \, \tau_3 := t_{2,1}, \, \tau_4 := t_{3,1}, \, \dots
$$
and writing $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} S_n = \pi_{\{\tau_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}}^{-1}\left( \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n \right)$, but this doesn't sit right with me.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you very much for your help!  Also, please give me feedback on how I can improve my questions on MSE as this is my first post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

For every subset $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ let $\bar{\Omega}_{S}$ denote
the set of functions $S\to\mathbb{R}$ and let it be equipped with
the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\bar{\Omega}_{S}$ such that for
every $s\in S$ function $\pi_{s}:\bar{\Omega}_{S}\to\mathbb{R}$
prescribed by $f\mapsto f\left(s\right)$ is measurable.

We denote this $\sigma$-algebra as $\mathcal{B}_{S}$ and it can
also be described as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylindrical
subsets of $\bar{\Omega}_{S}$.

For $K,L\in\mathcal{P}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ with $L\subseteq K$
let $\pi_{L}^{K}:\bar{\Omega}_{K}\to\bar{\Omega}_{L}$ be prescribed
by $\bar{\omega}\mapsto\bar{\omega}\upharpoonright L$ and abbreviate
$\pi_{L}^{\mathbb{R}}$ as $\pi_{L}$.

It is easily verified that every function $\pi_{L}^{K}$ is measurable.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the collection of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}.$

Then $A\in\Sigma\iff\exists K\in\mathcal{C}\exists B\in\mathcal{B}_{K}\left[A=\pi_{K}^{-1}\left(B\right)\right]$

Let $\left(A_{n}\right)_{n}$ denote a sequence of elements of $\Sigma$.

Then there is a sequence $\left(K_{n}\right)_{n}$ in $\mathcal{C}$
together with a sequence $\left(B_{n}\right)_{n}$ where $B_{n}\in\mathcal{B}_{K_{n}}$ such
that $A_{n}=\pi_{K_{n}}^{-1}\left(B_{n}\right)$

Here $K:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}K_{n}\in\mathcal{C}$ and writing $\pi_{K_{n}}=\pi_{K_{n}}^{K}\circ\pi_{K}$
we find that $A_{n}=\pi_{K}^{-1}\left(\left(\pi_{K_{n}}^{K}\right)^{-1}\left(B_{n}\right)\right)$.

Then: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\pi_{K}^{-1}\left(\left(\pi_{K_{n}}^{K}\right)^{-1}\left(B_{n}\right)\right)=\pi_{K}^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\pi_{K_{n}}^{K}\right)^{-1}\left(B_{n}\right)\right)$$

Here $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\pi_{K_{n}}^{K}\right)^{-1}\left(B_{n}\right)$
is a countable union of elements of $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{K}$ hence
is itself an element of $\mathcal{B}_{K}$ justifying the conclusion
that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ is an element of $\Sigma$.

Comment: Excellent!  This is super clear.  I really appreciate it. :)